# How to read/write .xpt file with Python?

Tags: python, sas

Am new to Python and looking for a solution to read/write xpt file(SAS data set) using Python.

I got to know its possible using Python from this [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xport/). But then the code is not working as expected. Anything missing in this code, whether to include any library or to install any library. Or even any syntax error in this code.

```
with open('example.xpt', 'rb') as f:
for row in xport.Reader(f):
    print row
```

Note: Am familiar with PHP scripting.

Please help me with suitable solution.

Comment: Don't you get any errors on execution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to import the package to use xport

```
Import xport
```

And have to install the package by

```
sudo pip install xport
```

Comment: thanks. its working